# What is Object Repository in Automation Testing?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

I'm new with Selenium.
Can you please explain What is Object Repository in Automation?
any example?

Comment: Where did you see the term?

Comment: what you want to ask? Is it related to only Selenium or whole automation?

Comment: Please prefer this below tutorial http://learn-automation.com/object-repository-in-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: I assume, this term is taken from HP UFT

Comment: No @olyv it is a general industry term for the automation objects and their identifiers

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Sorry if it seems like I am calling it into question, can I have a link to any software testing book where "Object Repository" term is used? I would really like to have it for future references

Comment: @olyv if yhou google https://www.google.com/search?q=selenium+object+repository&oq=selenium+object+repository&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j69i61.3718j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 the first three links are about QTP and Java, not HP UFT  The fifth link is about XML, etc, etc. Not sure why you need to question this when there's tons of info out there about this stuff

Comment: See also https://smile.amazon.com/Improve-Selenium-Code-Automation-Patterns-ebook/dp/B077QFN53F/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1514550226&sr=8-1-fkmr0&keywords=selenium+object+repository maybe if you use the term Page Object instead of Object Repository it will help

Comment: @MichaelDurrant The point is that Object Repository and Page Object pattern are slightly different things. Similar but different. As for googling, I did -- those web sites which I can see in search results are not official organisations or books or any other authority but somebodies thoughts like in blogspot let's say. And I am questioning this because " Object Repository != Page Object" . I would agree with statement "Page Object is industry term" but not with "Object Repository is industry term". Wide popularity of HP UFT doesn't make it standart

Comment: Sure.  I'm not that interested in precise definitions.  I focus on working software (including tests).  whatever it is called.  In the open source world I also shy away from seeking 'official' definitions.  Doesn't add value to me.

Comment: Basically, you can mix Object Repository (the one from HP UFT) and Page Object pattern. For example: http://olyv-qa.blogspot.co.uk/2016/11/hp-uft-applying-pageobject-pattern.html. It's nothing but Page Object, and yet ```objBrowser```and ```objPage``` can be moved to Object Repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Object Repository is a centralized location where we can store objects information, it acts as interface between Test script and application in order to identify the objects during the execution.**

We always recommend using external file for object repository rather than hard coding the objects and its properties directly into our code. If you are asking me why this is?
Reason is as it reduces the maintenance  effort and provides positive ROI, for example say any of the object properties change within our application under test, we can easily change it in external object repository file, rather than searching and doing updates  for that object individually in the code.

> EX: we use a **.properties file in Java**

Comment: Agree, an object repository (or UI map) is much more maintainable as you only have to monitor 1 file. A disadvantage would be that file can grow into hundreds of lines depending on the app. I personally will take maintaining 1 file over tons of PageObjects though.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree about the usefullness of the object repository in Selenium WebDriver test automation projects.

In my opinion, using object repositories in Selenium projects is a bad practice.

The object repository concept comes from record-and-playback tools such as QTP.

The object repository is a tree-like structure that is created while recording a test.

It has attributes for each element of the page used in the test.

Selenium does not have any record-and-play feature for test automation (Selenium IDE is not an automation tool).

Using object repositories in Selenium projects (as property or csv or xml files) has many disadvantages such as

1. since each locator is a line in a text file, it is impossible to open the declaration of the locator in the IDE (using F3 or Open Declaration)
2. page object classes with no locator variables break the class encapsulation principle (methods of a class should execute on variables of a class)
3. object repositories do not scale well for big pages; since big pages are bad and should be broken down in small pages, should we not have object repositories for each page widget?
4. object repositories do not work with page factory

Read more about the disadvantages on [this medium.com article](https://medium.com/@alexsiminiuc3/dont-use-object-repositories-with-selenium-webdriver-ad14096528e5).

Comment: i can use PO's in the selenium IDE.  I've scaled page objects fine, breaking them out into individual and shared objects as needed.  I just disagree with this answer.  From my experience in 3 companies I think these are incorrect points

Comment: PageObjects are overrated and become huge maintenance overhead for large applications. I have seen test suites with 50+ page object classes and it is a nightmare. Most automation testers are not exactly developers which makes PageObjects notorious for terrible implementations. Partly the tester's fault but also alludes to the fact that it is not tester friendly and takes great effort to maintain. Sooner or later, you will find yourself mercilessly refactoring PageObjects just to keep up as the application grows larger. It is also very AUT-specific which makes it unusable for other projects.

Answer (score 0):

It's where you define objects (meaning the HTML definition of web page parts) and how they are grouped into application pages and page sections that represent logical groupings of information in the application.

[See details here.](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/object-repository/)

*Think of a scenario where you have a Webpage and it has multiple sections, multiple frames and hundreds of WebElements. Obviously you do not want that once you type the page name and it will give you all the elements available on the webpage. If there are few elements, it is fine to have the same structure but if there are many then it is advisable to divide your page in to different sections for e.g. header, footer, left navigation, center content and right navigation. Then categories each WebElement under their parent element.*

Answer (score 0):

Object repositories are a collection of UI/Application object data recorded by the testing tool while exploring the application under test.